# How to exclude the manage package objects from all objects fetched through SOQL

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using below SOQL query to fetch all the objects related to one profile based on their access on the profile.

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsDelete
                                FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment))
                                AND
                                (PermissionsRead = true)
                                AND
                                ( Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true)
                                AND
                                (Parent.Profile.Name ='System Administrator')
```

This query working fine and returning all the objects related to sys admin profile which includes managed packages objects as well.

To remove the manage package objects from the fetched result, I am using below query.

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsDelete
                                FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment))
                                AND
                                (PermissionsRead = true)
                                AND
                                ( Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true)
                                AND
                                (Parent.Profile.Name ='System Administrator')
                                AND
                                (NOT SObjectType LIKE 'Flosum%')
```

Just added "(NOT SObjectType LIKE 'Flosum%')" this filter. But it is not working. Getting below error.

```
INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR: 
(NOT SObjectType LIKE 'Flosum%')
^
ERROR at Row:10:Column:17
invalid operator on id field
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it in another way. First describe the objects and create a set of object API names and then you can include that Set in your query.

```
Set<String> sobjectNames = new Set<String>();
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() ){
   Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
   system.debug( 'Sobject: ' + objResult );
   system.debug( 'Sobject API Name: ' + objResult.getName() );
   system.debug( 'Sobject Label Name: ' + objResult.getLabel() );   
   if(!objResult.getName().startsWith('Flosum')) {
      sobjectNames.add(objResult.getName());
   }
}
```

Now, you can use the **sobjectNames** list for your query.

Comment: Or even better would be to exclude all object which have double underscores..  So you dont have to add startsWith('newPackge'); everytime a new app is installed